# Center Tabs and Header in R Shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

I would like to center both my tabs and header within my R Shiny page. I have tried to use `div()` with `class=span7`, but it throws an error of missing an argument.

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    headerPanel("Header"),
    mainPanel(
        # Output: Tabset w/ headers ---
        tabsetPanel(type = 'tabs',
                    tabPanel('Tab1'),
                    tabPanel('Tab2',
                        sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel( # input
                                selectInput(id='tab2','Title',
                                    choices=c('A','B','C','D')),
                                submitButton("Submit"),
                                width=4
                            ),
                            mainPanel( # output
                                textOutput('text1')
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    )
    )
))
```

Then with wrap `div()` around `tabsetPanel()` as

```
div(
    tabsetPanel(....),
    class='span7'
)
```

Comment: The only error I can see is you use in `selectInput` `id='tab2'` instead of `inputId='tab2'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using a custom css style (and editing an existing shiny class):

**UI**

```r
fluidPage(theme='style.css',
    headerPanel(h1("Header", align='center')),
    mainPanel(
        # Output: Tabset w/ headers ---
        tabsetPanel(type = 'tabs',

                    tabPanel('Tab1'),
                    tabPanel('Tab2',
                             sidebarLayout(
                                 sidebarPanel( # input
                                     selectInput(inputId ='tab2','Title',
                                                 choices=c('A','B','C','D')),
                                     submitButton("Submit"),
                                     width=4
                                 ),
                                 mainPanel( # output
                                     textOutput('text1')
                                 )
                             )
                    )
                    ), class='flex-center'

        )
    )
```

**CSS**

I used flex to center the tabs. Also had to clear the float:left property that was set on one of the column classes.

```
.flex-center {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction:column;
  margin:auto;
}


.col-sm-8 {
  float:none;
}
```

Save the css as 'style.css' in a sub-folder called 'www' within your shiny project folder.

Comment: I can't just save the css within the file itself? But the subfolders are essentially `Doc/ShinyProj/www/style.css` and my shiny project is `Doc/ShinyProj/ui.R`? When I create the css is it within an R file and just saved as css, or something else?

Comment: yep just create a file (can be in Rstudio or text editor) as .css https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html might be helpful too

Comment: Very helpful. I haven't really dug into style with css before, but I am also assuming there are ways to control the page size when it first opens up? Because I have 5 tabs, but when I click run app, 4 are on 1 line and another is on the line below. I know that's an extra question but if you have any insightful tips, that would be super helpful.

Comment: I'm not getting that problem with many tabs. Do you mean the shiny app window is too small when first loading? If so, that wouldn't be fixed by css! Maybe click on 'open in browser' as a workaround?

Comment: Well, it's more white space around the tabs I guess to better describe it. But let me look into it more and if anything post a different question to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer would be rather than defining new styles, look at the styles currently being applied and edit those. You can see the css selectors by opening up your app in the browser and using chrome developer tools.

```r
fluidPage(theme='style.css',
                title = 'my app',
    headerPanel(
        h1("Header", align='center')),
        # Output: Tabset w/ headers ---
        tabsetPanel(type = 'tabs',
                    tabPanel('Tab1'),
                    tabPanel('Tab2',
                             sidebarLayout(
                                 sidebarPanel( # input
                                     selectInput(inputId ='tab2','Title',
                                                 choices=c('A','B','C','D')),
                                     submitButton("Submit"),
                                     width=12
                                 ),
                                 mainPanel( # output
                                     textOutput('text1')
                                 )
                             )
                    ),
                    tabPanel('Tab3'),
                    tabPanel('Tab4'),
                    tabPanel('Tab5')

                    ), class='tab-panel'


    )
```

The css selector for the tabs turns out to be `.nav-tabs` so I've set that to display flex and centered.

I also defined a `tab-panel` class and set all of the divs within that to be 100% width which I think fixes your white space issue?

```css
.nav-tabs {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  width: 100%;
}

.col-sm-8 {
  float:none;
}

.tab-panel > div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: So, this way actually aligns everything to the left, which removes the white space on the left.

Comment: Strange, it aligns it all central for me. Did you update both the app and the css?

Comment: Realized the issue. Needed to have both of the css stuff you wrote in the css file itself. Not one or the other.