# How would you create a Shiny navbar with centered multiple line title and centered anchors?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a specific looking Shiny app with the following features in the navbar:

- multiple lines of text (a title and subtitle)
- underneath are anchors that link back to different sections in the page.

How do I approach this? I'm not sure how to get `navbarPage()` to accept multiple lines in the text, and how to get it to centre and have anchors.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this example in the Shiny Gallery: https://shiny.posit.co/r/gallery/life-sciences/hospital-data-antimicrobial/  - it has a spanned, rather than centred, tab bar, but the implementation should give you some possiblities to investigate.

Comment: Also some leads in the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59256579/16730940